# Maven build multiple jars from one project with unique constant in each jar

Tags: maven, jar, sbt, pom.xml, build-server

Rather than necrobump [Multiple builds in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093197/multiple-builds-in-maven) and attempt to work with the (now unmaintained) maven plugin created as a result of that thread, I'll present my current dilemma.

We create a separate jar for each of our end users. The only thing unique in each one of them is a constant.

The number of end users frequently changes, so using profiles/modules/assembly config in the pom.xml will frequently change and is impractical for a CI/CD pipeline.

Therefore, at build time we need to somehow have maven:

1. Determine the number of unique jars to build.
2. Create a build for each, with each having its unique constant.

How does one go about doing this?

We already have a separate script that creates a list of all users and their associated constant value. We just don't know how to get maven to dynamically use this list at build time.

How does one do this with maven? Is there a different build tool we should use to do this? If so, which and how?

Comment: What is the reason that you do not read the constant from a property file outside the JAR?

Comment: I would just edit the script and call mvn clean install (or package, depending on your needs) and pass as a property with "-Dsomeproperty=propety value" and then in the pom declare this property 
```<properties>
    <someproperty> ${someproperty} </someproperty>
</properties>
``` This way you can use the property in the way you want to.

Comment: also the question looks similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67279588/maven-build-multiple-jars-from-one-project-with-unique-constant-in-each-jar It's just not answered

Comment: @JFabianMeier because we would like to obfuscate the constant value.

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov thanks. Something like this may work. Though, if I understand you correctly, this would require us to have another automation script to loop through our User+Constant list and run a maven build for each, no?

Comment: @DavidHabibi it could be done in the same script I guess, but yes, it could be done with another simple script